# HTTP DELETE always returns a HTTP/400 error message

Tags: java, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-400, http-delete

I tried doing a HTTP DELETE by the below code, but always received an error message of Status 400, I wanted to know if I had done sonething wrong. I'm not too sure whether I need to use 'httpCon.getInputStream();'

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL("http://testurl.svc/web/testrequests/"+893488);

        StringBuffer xmlString = new StringBuffer();

        xmlString.append("<TestRequest>");
        xmlString.append("<DateRequested>2011-12-23</DateRequested>");
        xmlString.append("<ID>893488</ID>");
        xmlString.append("<Version>1</Version>");
        xmlString.append("<TestID>19104</TestID>");
        xmlString.append("<ProjectName>LTS</ProjectName>");
        xmlString.append("<RequestedBy>ktmq331</RequestedBy>");
        xmlString.append("<SampleNumber>SN1033646000</SampleNumber>");
        xmlString.append("<Status>Requested</Status>");
        xmlString.append("</TestRequest>");

        System.out.println("xmlString :" + xmlString.toString());

        System.out.println("URL : " + url);

        try {
            System.out.println("URL : " + url);
            HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
            httpCon.setDoOutput(true); 
            httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml"); 
            httpCon.setRequestMethod("DELETE"); 
            httpCon.connect();
            httpCon.getInputStream();
            int responseCode = httpCon.getResponseCode();
            System.out.print("Response Code: "+responseCode);
            String responseString = httpCon.getResponseMessage();
            System.out.print("Response Message: "+responseString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're doing a delete, the request should not be of type text/xml (You're not even using the xmlString variable anyway).

Basically make sure this is set:

```
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
```

Instead of this:

```
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
```

And you won't need getInputStream().

Comment: I still receive the same error message.. Can you please verify whether the the method of calling HHTP DELETE is correct ?

Comment: What I need to do is to delete the value present in the following URL "http://testurl.svc/web/testrequests/"+893488" using the http DELETE method.